# LocalNotification repeatingInterval value for weekly notification

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I already check a lot of Questions here in Stackoverflow and also checked the apple documentation. So, please no need to declare this question as duplicated.

I am using swift and trying to create a **local notification that repeats every Friday**. The problem that I don't know which value to use, *with the `repeatInterval` attribute*, and what is the difference between all of these ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/c:@E@NSCalendarUnit)):

- Weekday
- WeekdayOrdinal
- WeekOfMonth
- WeekOfYear

And as usual, the apple documentation is not easy to understand, at least for me :(

Comment: weekday is what you're looking for.

Comment: @D.Greg thats not correct. If he needs to repeat the notification every week  weekOfYear is the unit he needs to use. To make it repeat every friday he needs to set the firedate to the next friday at the desired time.

Comment: I'll look into it. thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

*Weekday* is a number from 1 to 7 where Sunday is represented by 1 and the other days so forth until Saturday which is represented by 7.
**This is the one you're looking for**

*WeekOfMonth* is exactly how it sounds. 2 would be the second week of each month, 3 would be the third week of each month, etc.

*WeekOfYear* is similar and interpreted according to the calendar. So 3rd week is 3rd week of the year, etc.

WeekdayOrdinal is probably the one that's most confusing. Here's the definition according to Apple Documentation.

> Weekday ordinal units represent the position of the weekday within the
>   next larger calendar unit, such as the month. For example, 2 is the
>   weekday ordinal unit for the second Friday of the month.

Comment: Thank you 'Josh Hamet' for the explanation. But I think the solution is, as @LeoDabus said,  **WeekOfYear**.